# Why is my AWS assumed role not authorised to perform cognito-idp:AdminGetUser?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, laravel-vapor

My Laravel application calls the [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) endpoint.

In the local environment, it successfully returns the resource.

After deploying to a Vapor environment, it fails with the following error message:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/laravel-vapor-role/xxxx is not authorized to perform: **cognito-idp:AdminGetUser** on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:xxxx:userpool/us-east-1_xxxx because no identity-based policy allows the cognito-idp:AdminGetUser action
```

What is the issue?

Comment: IAM roles, what are the policies for laravel vapo role?

Comment: that role has 14 services allowed, what is the required service for this api call?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary there were `CloudWatch,CloudWatch Logs,DynamoDB,EC2,KMS,Lambda,Pinpoint Email,Route 53 Domains,S3,Secrets Manager,SES,SES v2,SQS,Systems Manager` allowed. with your comment I got the idea and added new service of `Cognito User Pools` which solves the issue. Please  add an answer with explanation so I can accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> laravel-vapor-role is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminGetUser on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:xxxx:userpool/us-east-1_xxxx

This means the `laravel-vapor-role` role does not have a suitable policy attached to provide it with permission to carry out the `cognito-idp:AdminGetUser` action.

You can fix this in 2 ways:

1. Assign the AWS managed `AmazonCognitoReadOnly` policy to the role
2. Add an inline policy to the role, in line with the security best practice of [granting least privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege)

---

If you anticipate more read-only permissions will be needed later on, it'll be much easier and better to just assign the AWS managed `AmazonCognitoReadOnly` policy to the role.

It will provides permissions for read-only access to your identity pools and user pools, including the `cognito-idp:AdminGetUser` permission that falls under `cognito-idp:Get*` (documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/cognito/latest/developerguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html), direct policy link [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoReadOnly)):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:Describe*",
                "cognito-identity:Get*",
                "cognito-identity:List*",
                "cognito-idp:Describe*",
                "cognito-idp:AdminGet*",
                "cognito-idp:AdminList*",
                "cognito-idp:List*",
                "cognito-idp:Get*",
                "cognito-sync:Describe*",
                "cognito-sync:Get*",
                "cognito-sync:List*",
                "iam:ListOpenIdConnectProviders",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "sns:ListPlatformApplications"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

If you only require the single permission of `cognito-idp:AdminGetUser`, then create & assign an inline policy to the role which only grants that permission for the specific Cognito User Pool.

The below images should be self-explanatory:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this, the issue for me was that I borrowed the `iamRoleStatements` configuration from another file but forgot to include `serverless-iam-roles-per-function` import at the top of my file.

```
plugins:
    - serverless-pseudo-parameters
    - serverless-iam-roles-per-function # <----- Missing this plugin *****

functions:
    func1:
        handler: handler.func1
        iamRoleStatements:
            - Effect: 'Allow'
              Action:
                  - sns:Publish
              Resource: 'arn:aws:sns:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:EventsTopic'
```