# CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

getting above error while calling AdminGetUserCommand, for user methods its working fine. but while using admin method its not working.

also i have add policies in IAM by refering following

[Why is my AWS assumed role not authorised to perform cognito-idp:AdminGetUser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596447/why-is-my-aws-assumed-role-not-authorised-to-perform-cognito-idpadmingetuser)

here is code for referenace

```
 private config = {
    region: process.env.COGNITO_REGION,
  };
  private userPoolId = process.env.COGNITO_USERPOOL_ID || "";
  private clientId = process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID || "";
  private secretHash = process.env.COGNITO_SECRET || "";

  private cognitoIdentity: CognitoIdentityProviderClient;

  constructor() {
    this.cognitoIdentity = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(this.config);
  }

  getUserbyId = async (id: string) => {
    const input = {
      UserPoolId: this.userPoolId,
      Username: id,
    };

    try {
      const adminGetUserCommand = new AdminGetUserCommand(input);

      const user = await this.cognitoIdentity.send(adminGetUserCommand);

      console.log(user);

      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: private config = {
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION || "",
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY || "",
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY || "",
    },
  }; load config like this. and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69596447/why-is-my-aws-assumed-role-not-authorised-to-perform-cognito-idpadmingetuser and give permissions from this link.